# Objective-C pathForResource doesn't find file, returns null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

The code i'm using below doesn't seem to find the file i want, can anyone help?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iTunes Music Library" ofType:@".xml" inDirectory:@"~/Music/iTunes/"];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is looking inside your bundle, so it would be something like `/Applications/My App.app/Contents/Resources/~/Music/iTunes` (if "~" there is even legal). You're not looking for a bundle resource here. Why are you making this call to find the path of a file you already know the path to?

Comment: In addition to this, it's also looking for a file named "iTunes Music Library..xml". The type should just be `@"xml"`.